# animation:transition when toggle

Tags: html, css

Have a scenario where, when I click, I need to apply toggle transition.

Here is my html code:

```
<div ng-class="{'col-xs-6': myVar=='something'}">
<div class="panel panel-default panel-height" ng-repeat="candidateInfo in aCandidateDetails track by $index">
    <div class="panel-heading header-background">
        <div stop-watch time="xyz" name="candidateInfo.name" time-of-interview="candidateInfo.doi" class="stop-watch"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2"><a style="cursor:pointer" class="pull-right">{{candidateInfo.name}}</a></div>
            <div class="col-xs-offset-9"><a style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="fnVar()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{'#'+toggle}}">{{candidateInfo.name}} resume</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="{{toggle}}" class="collapse" ng-class="{'col-xs-6': myVar=='something'}">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

so when I click I need to apply `col-xs-6` class with transition

Here is my css code:

```
.col-xs-6 {
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}
```

I am not getting correct transition. I need transition same as side bar toggle

Comment: please provide full CSS code

Answer (score 0):

Use ngAnimate

```
.col-xs-6.ng-enter {
   transition-property: all;
   opacity:0
    transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

.col-xs-6.ng-enter-active {
  opacity :1
}
```

Comment: It is the same now also